# SML - How to check if 2 parameters are the same in pattern matching?

Tags: parameters, pattern-matching, sml

I have this piece of code which calulates the hanoi movement and returns them as a list. This works so far.

```
fun hanoi(0,start,ziel) = []
  | hanoi(1,start,ziel) = [(1,start,ziel)]
  | hanoi(anz,start,ziel) = hanoi(anz-1,start,hilf(start,ziel)) 
                   @ ((anz,start,ziel)::hanoi(anz-1,hilf(start,ziel),ziel))
and hilf(start,ziel) = 6-(start+ziel);
```

Now my question is how can I check for the last pattern in which start and the goal (german: ziel) is the same? I tried something like this:

```
|hanoi(anz,start,ziel=start) = []
```

but it did not work. Seems like I am having problems understanding the concept of pattern matching fully. But I couldn't find much helpful ressources.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't check for this, because `start=ziel` is not a pattern -- patterns are (for the most part) values or special patterns like `_` or variable names, while `start = ziel` is an expression that is not fully evaluated.

Instead, pattern match to extract `start` and `ziel`, and then you can either case on or use an if statement to do different things depending on whether or not `start = ziel`.

For example:

```
| hanoi(anz, start, ziel) = if start = ziel
                            then ...
                            else ...
```

or

```
| hanoi(anz, start, ziel) = case start = ziel of
                              true => ...
                            | false => ...
```

These two options do the same thing -- which to use is a stylistic decision.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that a typical restriction on patterns is *linearity* (i.e., every variable may occur at most once in the pattern). That is the reason why it is not possible to check equality with a pattern alone.

Comment: @chris, this restriction is not a reason (or else, how?), and also this restriction seems to me to be arbitrary (unless there is a formal foundation I don't know). To have a variable appearing twice could just mean an equality and I often missed this in SML (one can work around this lack, but that's less clean and breaks readability). There was a proposal to add guards to SML patterns, but no interpreter/compiler implements this.

Comment: @Hibou57: Maybe I'm not getting what you are heading at. Anyway, if patterns would allow non-linearity then checking for equality of `x` and `y` would be easy: just match `(x, y)` against the pattern `(z, z)`. I'm not sure about the technical reasons in programming languages for not having non-linear patterns though. I can only guess that it is about performance.